# How to get result after run .bat as admin - C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, admin

I'm trying to get the result, yes or no, that users press to answer a program when run as admin.

Example:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Get5.png)

I'm trying with the following code:

```
var processInstall = new ProcessStartInfo();
            processInstall.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInstall.FileName = "myBatchFileAddress";
            processInstall.Verb = "runas";
            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = processInstall;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
            //Here I must deal  with the result of user, if is yes or no
```

Comment: That image is Window's UAC, you won't get the answer of that. You can even disable it so it's never shown. If 'yes' the process will execute, else it won't

Answer (score 0):

Batch files are a very old technology. **Literally** as old as DOS. So by their nature, the ability to communicate is limited.

DOS era programms primarily communicated via "ERRORLEVEL". The return in Console programm still affects said errorlevel. 0 was returned for "no problem". Anything else for a problem. Batchfiles could check it. And I am 90% certain windows actually still uses it - if a setup returns anything but 0, it asks "should I try again with compatibility settings?" Using EXIT you can define wich ERRORLEVEL the batchfile "returns".

However there is another way to, depending on how verbose the programms are: [IO redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx).

Keep in mind that batchfiles are interpreted. So you ahve to run the *console* programm, then give the order to run teh console (usually as a parameter with full path; see console documentation for details).

Finally executing any batchfile as adminsitrator tends to screw up the paths utterly. The batchfile needs to be [designed to compensate](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/119828/Running-a-bat-file-as-administrator-Correcting-cur).

Of course if those programms are written by yourself, you have options like Interprocess Communication. But I asume this was not the case right now.

Edit: It seems I missunderstood the question. If a programm asks for Adminsitrative privileges due to a Manifest or is run with runas but the elevation is denied, the execution is never done at all. The programm is not even started by Windows. It is Propably not even loaded into memory.

Comment: "Edit: It seems I missunderstood the question. If a programm asks for Adminsitrative privileges due to a Manifest or is run with runas but the elevation is denied, the execution is never done at all. The programm is not even started by Windows. It is Propably not even loaded into memory."

And, how could I know which option the user selected?

Comment: Please delete everything from your answer that's not relevant to this question